# What is the quickest way to change the classes of multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the classes of a group of elements into other classes. The current classes of the elements are all different and so are the classes I want to change their current classes in to.

Currently, the best idea I have is to check the current class of the element, and then change it according to its class, repeating this for the amount of elements I need to change. For example, if I wanted to change all elements with the class 'a' to the class 'z' and 'b' to 'y' etc., I would do this:

```
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' , 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
var classes_product = ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'q', 'p', 'o', 'n', 'm', 'l', 'k', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'];
for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(classes[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        x[j].className = classes_product[i];
    }
}
```

I tried to resolve this problem myself but all I could find was the ability to change the class using ".className". I would really appreciate another method that doesn't require as much typing because I need to make quite a few changes for some of my functions to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is buggy.

- `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection. If you remove a class from an element while iterating over the collection, the collection's elements will shift down; your current implementation will skip some elements.
- Since some of the resulting classes are the same as the initial classes, changing, eg `a` to `z` will, at the end of the loop, change those back to `a`.

While you could construct a collection of all matching elements in advance, then iterate over them, helped by a mapping of classes to their results...

```
const classTransformations = {
    a: 'z',
    b: 'y',
    c: 'x',
    // ...
};

Object.entries(classTransformations)
    .map(([initial, final]) => ({ elements: document.querySelectorAll('.' + initial), final }))
    .forEach(({ elements, final }) => {
        for (const elm of elements) elm.classList = final;
    });
```

It'd probably be better to take a step back and think about *what* changing all of these classes is intended to do, and if there's a DRY-er way to do so.

If, as your original code appears to show, you only need to toggle between two states, you could toggle a single class on a single parent element, and change your CSS rules appropriately, so that, eg `.parent .a` results in the rules for the initial `a` class, and `.parent.toggled .a` results in the rules for the toggled `z` class.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm still very new to programming so I don't know anything apart from the basics, but I think I've managed to gather the main idea of the code you have given, could you please check my understanding? The first line (Object.entries...) loops through the "classTransformations" and then the next line creates an array of the elements with the key as their class and then the next lines loop through the elements, changing their class. Additionally, what does "elm of elements" mean?

Comment: `for..of` iterates through items of a collection. So, `elm` is each item in the `elements` collection. The `Object.entries` returns an array of entries - of the key-value pairs of the object being iterated over, eg `[['a', 'z'], ['b', 'y'], ...`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var classes_product = ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a'];
classes.forEach(function (item) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(item);
  for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    const element = x[j];
    element.classList.add(classes_product[j]);
    element.classList.remove(item);
  }
});
```

```css
.a {
  color: red;
}
.b {
  color: blue;
}
.c {
  color: green;
}
.d {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</div>
```